# Download image from a php function called with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this ajax:

```
 $('.getid').on('click', function(){
        var imagename =  $(this).data("id");
        // you can make ajax call here to get data
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Monitor/downloadDesiredImage",
        data: {'val' : imagename},
        dataType: "text"
        }).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);        
       }).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  });
});
```

This will work with a button that will send on.click a id value saved in a var imagename, that is a string that correspond to a image name saved on my server.

This is the php function that will get that id :

```
public function downloadDesiredImage() {
        $imagename = $_POST['val'];
        echo "this is my ".  $imagename;
        $file = file_get_contents('./images/'.$imagename.'.jpg', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
        $imageData = base64_encode(($file));
        $src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($file).';base64,'.$imageData;
        echo '<img src="' . $src . '">';

    }
```

That will output the image in the network response, but I will also get the error :

> Message: mime_content_type(): Invalid path

But what I want to do is after I click the button is to download that image from my server. How I can do that ? Thanks!

Comment: You could create an <a> -Tag with the image-href and trigger the click on it. No need of php-processing...

Answer (score 2):

`mime_content_type()` expects the file *name*, not the data of the file itself.  Something like this:

```
mime_content_type('./images/'.$imagename.'.jpg')
```

Comment: Cool, got that, it works, but how I can actually download that image that I get when I press the button ? I only see the image in the network output response from chrome developer tool.

Comment: @TatuBogdan: If you're seeing the response in the network tab then you are successfully downloading the image.  I guess the question becomes... What do you want to *do* with that image once it's downloaded?

Comment: echo '<img src="' . $src . '">'; I think this will only display it, won't download it, I don't download nothing when I click the button.

Comment: @TatuBogdan: Well, that would display it from PHP, but not from JavaScript since that's not JavScript code.  Displaying an image would involve downloading the image of course, since the browser needs to get the data in order to display it.  It's not really clear what you're trying to do or what isn't working.

Comment: I want to download it to my computer let's say, like a normal download.

Comment: @TatuBogdan: You want to save it as a file?  That would generally require prompting the user, since JavaScript doesn't really have a lot of access to the file system (for obvious security reasons).  AJAX might not be the way to go at all here.  You might instead consider making it a full page-level request, and have the server respond with the right `Content-Disposition` header to indicate that it's a file being downloaded.  The browser *should* prompt the user to save the file without unloading the current page.